# How to know the text files developed in particular OS like UNIX or Windows?

Tags: java, file

I want to know the which Operating System (e.g.: UNIX or Windows or MAC) is used to Develop Text File and it's File Format (e.g.: UTF-8 or ANSI or DOS) by using Java. If I read one text file using Java Application, I want to know which Operating System is used to develop that File and it's File Format.

How to do this using Java Application? Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that a text file store this informations?

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you need. Anyway, the different OS'es have different conventions for the line termination (\r or \n or \r\n) and for the encoding (cp1252 or utf-8 etc.). But any of these files can be produced on any of these OS'es.

Comment: I know the line terminations.But, How to do this using java code whether the line terminates \r or \n.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file as binary data (as opposed to textual) and examine for \r or \n or \r\n.